# Error while trying to get String Array from strings.xml

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-ndk

I have 2 and 1 huge array of strings in strings.xml file, it wrapped in  tag.

When I trying to get data using **`getResources().getStringArray(R.array.some_name)`** first two arrays work fine, but last one with the huge amount of data (long content of each item) throws an error on some phones (for example on my Nexus 6p Android 8.1 (official)). I tried to minimize data of an array but still gets error.

Here is error log:

```
05-22 11:36:09.541 15746-15746/kvazios.mylifestory A/zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: chars == null && char_count > 0
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]     in call to NewString
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]     from java.lang.String[] android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(int)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x72bf25f0 self=0x7b51abea00
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | sysTid=15746 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7bd657d9a8
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | state=R schedstat=( 3054541310 145051602 2178 ) utm=278 stm=26 core=4 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | stack=0x7fdb54b000-0x7fdb54d000 stackSize=8MB
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #00 pc 00000000003ccb5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+208)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #01 pc 000000000049cdf4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+348)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #02 pc 00000000002fe388  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1048)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #03 pc 00000000002fe878  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+180)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #04 pc 000000000037ccdc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+992)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #05 pc 00000000001017c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::NewString(_JNIEnv*, unsigned short const*, int)+664)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #06 pc 000000000011a088  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   native: #07 pc 00000000004834c4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_content_res_AssetManager_getArrayStringResource__I+132)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceStringArray(AssetManager.java:208)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:573)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at kvazios.mylifestory.DescriptionActivity.loadOffline(DescriptionActivity.java:888)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at kvazios.mylifestory.DescriptionActivity.onCreate(DescriptionActivity.java:108)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java:-1)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
    java_vm_ext.cc:534]
```

Comment: I don't think you can assume that you don't run out of memory on _any_ phone just because it doesn't happen on some phones. Do you still get the same problem if you reduce the array down to just one string containing one character?

Comment: Hello! I reduced array from 100 to 30 items, still same problem. (No chance to reduce to 1 before next morning)

Comment: I'm too facing the same problem! I hope someone finds a solution for this.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in samsung on7 pro, but working fine in moto device.  I think  it is due to some special character in string file but not able to identify chars. If you find any solution, please share here